# How to make a call from angular application to .net core web api in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I have created docker image for angular and .net core api and deployed in the azure kubernetes. I have used Ingress controller for angular to expose outside of the cluster. I would like to know how to make a http call from angular app to core api which is exposed as ClusterIP service(Without exposing outside).

For Example: http://xxxxxxxxxx/api/test (from angular app)
here what is the value of xxxxxxxxxxx.?
Or How can we make a call.?

Could you please suggest with example.?

Comment: mate, consider accepting this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every service you create in kubernetes has a dns name (two actually):

1. service_name:service_port
2. service_name.namespace_name.svc.cluster.local:service_port

they will always resolve to the proper ip address to talk to your service (as long as kubernetes functions properly).

so just create a service for your api and use this notation to access it.

Reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Thank you. As you said, I have called my API service (congestion-latest) from angular app like 'http://congestion-latest:80/api/galorebridge/test'.

But I am getting following error,

polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://congestion-latest.default/api/galorebridge/test'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: this is a completely different problem, I suggest you accept this answer and raise a new question.

Comment: Yes, if this error is completely different, then i raise new question. Thank you for your answer.